# How to view my Google Searches archive on my S6?

Tags: google

[image]

I downloaded the SEARCHES archive from Google web history but when I open it with a HTML viewer or any other app it looks like a bunch of gibberish/code on the screen.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use [this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu) to understand that Gibberish or download a JSON viewer to make the stuff understandable. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016226/can-you-recommend-me-a-json-viewer-application) or [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18839/json-viewer-for-windows). On a side note, [this is JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Comment: @Firelord  Any viewers for Android though?

Comment: The first one I mentioned is an online viewer.

Comment: Use an Online [JSON beautifier](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) or [JSON to HTML converter](http://json.bloople.net/). You can also convert it to xml or csv if you wish.

Comment: Any leads here?